# p4 diff2 command output explanation

Tags: perforce

I tried p4 diff2 command. Please help me in understanding the command's output. Specifically I want to understand the lines like following

```
1c1   
3a4,5    
6a9   
13a17,18  
2,7d1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty typical; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81998/understanding-of-diff-output for a very similar description.

Lines which were (a)dded, (c)hanged, or (d)eleted are prefixed by these entries.

The numbers are line numbers from either the source file or the target file.

So `1c1` means that line 1 in the source was changed, resulting in line 1 in the target.

And `13a17,18` means that lines 17-18 in the target were added after line 13 in the source.

And `2,7d1` means that lines 2 through 7 in the source were deleted before line 1 in the target.